# Deploying JAVA WEB APP (netbeans) to AWS or GOOGLE APP ENGINE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, netbeans, amazon-web-services

Hey I am new to cloud computing.

I developed a java web app using netbeans. I now have been trying to deploy it onto google app engine and AWS for over a week.

In case of **GAE** it is showing the error of not supporting ***javax.servlet.annotation*** which I need to get the servlet context.

In case of **AWS**, it is successfully uploaded and deployed, however, on open link it gives a blank page.

Please somebody help me.

I have one more conceptual doubt which I couldn't find answer to.
In netbeans, I have a database. How is this database provided on GAE or AWS.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need much more information for this. I can only speak for AWS.

Where is the page hosted? What sort of errors is your application spitting out. What's the source of the page look like? Are you sure it's actually empty?

If it's returning a 200 and it's blank, that mean the page DOES exist, it's just not populating the page with what you want.

Comment: but thats the doubt nothing is being returned. its blank. there is no error if i build this app on glassfish. when i try elasticbeans it gets uploaded successfully but then there is nothing on the web page that opens up

http://awseb-e-7-awsebloa-1c955kbl5uc2j-1210736791.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Look at the developer tools for that page. It's definitely returning some stuff. Analytics, coupons_support2.js, a post to /gps, a progress-dots.gif, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Deploying an application at your local server setup and at the cloud is no different provided the cloud machine (AMI in case of amazon) has the server installed. Please share the exception or error log which you are getting. Also, have a look at amazon [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) where you can set up your database.

Comment: Yeah, i just made setup an RDS, now i trying to run that in my netbeans.

BUT in case of AWS no exception is being generated. i am using elastic beans. it successfully uploads and gives a blank page.

[link] (http://awseb-e-7-awsebloa-1c955kbl5uc2j-1210736791.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com/)

Comment: No, I mean you must be using amazon ec2, and you must have deployed a Web container(tomcat etc) there. In your application you must be logging something, is that being printed and are there any exceptions there? Surely, if your application did not find a DB it must have cried out something.. I am looking for those kind of exceptions, or in case of tomcat what is there in your catalina.out ??